# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Position'

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I'm modifying React js to ts now. It is Class Componenet.

I want to get css settings by props and apply it to Element.

How should I fix this?

```
render(){return(
<span style={{
          position: this.props.position ,
          left: this.props.left,
          top: this.props.top,
          height: this.props.height,
          width: this.props.width
     }} /> </span>)}
```

Comment: Could you please also attach your `props` type?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typescript expects the string to be literally one of the options of the `position` property - `absolute`, `relative` etc
One way to solve it is to tell it that you know the type will be ok, like so :

```
<span style={{
          position: this.props.position,
          left: this.props.left,
          top: this.props.top,
          height: this.props.height,
          width: this.props.width
     }:  as React.CSSProperties} /> </span>)}
```

Another option is to go where the position property is originally defined (parent element) and let Typescript enforce type, for example:

```
const styles: ('absolute' | 'relative' | 'fixed') = 'absolute';
```

Comment: Thank yo so much. Spend hours for this simple solution.

Comment: happy to help, typescript in react can be quite challenging.

Answer (score 7):

There is no need to cast the object but declare the type `React.CSSProperties` when initializing.

```
  function MyComponent(props) {
    const styles: React.CSSProperties = {
      position: this.props.position,
      left: this.props.left,
      top: this.props.top,
      height: this.props.height,
      width: this.props.width
    };


    return (
      <span style={styles}></span>
    );
  }
```

Comment: This is definitely the better answer. It provides some type protections, instead of (as the accepted answer puts it) asserting that "you know the type will be ok."